# Why the changes I made in the Django model not being reflected in the html form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

- I have a field named 'amount' of type Floatfield.
- I changed it to DecimalField and ran makemigrations and migrate commands and it successfully generated 0002_alter_expense_amount.py file.
- This change is  reflected in the database.

**But in the html form when I try to add new amount** [It's showing this message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye5Cw.png)
**When I tried the same from the admin panel it was successful**

**What should I do to make the html form accept the decimal value? Is there anything I'm missing?**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Expense(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/authentication/login")
def add_expenses(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'values': request.POST
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        amount = request.POST['amount']
        description = request.POST['description']
        date = request.POST['expense_date']
        category = request.POST['category']

        Expense.objects.create(owner=request.user, amount=amount, date=date, category=category, description=description)
        messages.success(request, 'Expense saved successfully')
        return redirect('expenses')
    else:    
        return render(request, 'expenses/add-expenses.html', context)
```

**html form**

```
    <form action="{% url 'add-expenses' %}" method="post">
        {% include 'partials/messages.html' %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="">Categories</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control" name="category" required>
                {% for category in categories%}
                <option name="category" value="{{category.name}}">
                    {{category.name}}
                </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="">Amount</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="amount" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="description" value="{{values.description}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="">Date</label>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-3">
                <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="expense_date" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-3">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: you should create a `forms.py` file to handle forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/

Comment: HTML inputs of type number do not accept decimals by default, but you can change this by using [step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#controlling_step_sizes), so `<input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="amount" required />`.  However, I would agree that using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) would be a much better approach.